# Hyphenation: Should it be context dependence or context-dependence?

Tags: hyphenation

This question is about hyphens in nouns. Grammarly suggests *context-dependence*, whereas I'm used to writing *context dependence*. I used to write the adjective as *context-dependent* but the noun without hyphen. Now I'm unsure, thanks to Grammarly's insistence. This is for a contribution to a Springer volume with presumably more US than UK authors. I'm a non-native speaker.

Which one would you recommend and why?

(Side note: What about *dependency* versus *dependence*? I used to write *dependency* but it started to sound kind of stilted to me and so I switched.)

Answer (score 0):

If I were reading a piece of text, I wouldn't be concerned either way. Both make sense. There are some occasions where using a hyphen is vital to prevent ambiguity, but in this instance it's not essential.

Comment: If you gave examples where hyphenated compound words are normally used and explain when they are necessary, you'll probably attract a few upvotes. There is no mention of context-dependency vs context-dependence either.

Comment: That's a good point, I will do so @Mari-LouA

Comment: On EL&U details, and references matter a lot more than on ELL. I note that your answers generally tend to be succinct. It works if you build a reputation for being an authority, and if the answers are simple but also accurate. Here the answer doesn't really give any useful information that a learner could apply to other contexts.